# Why would system be writing files on behalf of my process?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Sometime, System (PID 4) would write file on behalf of other process, why ?

This is not specific to a program, it would sometime write on behalf of TrustedInstaller, w3wp, Transmission or Syncthing, the later two being run without any kind of special privileges.

Comment: I don't know why this happens (good question!) but I can confirm that it isn't specific to your system, I've seen this lots of times on various different machines.  Something to do with caching perhaps?

Comment: Where are you seeing this in a Process Monitor trace?  If so, can you provide an example and show the stack trace?

Comment: @HelpingHand, I don't know about the OP, but when I've seen this happen it was in Resource Monitor.

Comment: Yup, ressource monitor